# CakePHP - making sure CakeEmail error not stopping the script and continuing with the rest

Tags: php, email, cakephp, smtp

I'm using `CakeEmail` to send out email campaigns using our own SMTP server.

During a campaign sending, I noticed that one email (in ~1000) failed to be sent because the address doesn't exist or malfunctioned (or being blocked by anti-spam).

However, instead of continuing with the rest, the script (which is called by a cron tab through a shell command) stopped with an error reported in the command line (I think the error code was 510 or so). I had to run the command manually to make sure the rest got sent.

The email sending code is quite ordinary:

```
// ...
$email->from($settings['from'])
            ->to($to)
            ->subject($settings['subject'])
            ->replyTo($settings['reply_to'])
            ->returnPath($settings['return_path']);

return $email->send($body);
// ...
```

Now, how do I make sure the script won't stop and keep going despite one or many emails are failed to be sent?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I make sure the script won't stop and keep going

Depends on the kind of error. [Read this](http://university.utest.com/writing-quality-bug-reports-and-utest-etiquette/) and report the exact error next time.

I assume it's an exception: Just use [exception handling, try / catch](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) to catch them, log the error if needed and continue.

Comment: Would the exception catching stops the script from executing?